# Excel vba userform setting cell interior doesn't go to next row

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox, colors

I am trying to make a userform and I want it to change the color of the next cell. It works everytime when I just use strings but every time I try to change the cell interior, it stays on the same row instead of going 1 row down like it should.
When I run it without the color part, everything works just fine and the strings go to the next row every time I want them to. But when I insert the cell color interior part it doesn't go 1 down.
I want to make it that if the checkbox is checked, the first column of the row is in green and if it isn't checked, it's red.

Here's the code:

```
Private Sub btnEnter_Click()
Dim ssheet As Worksheet

If Me.tbTitle.Value = "" Or Me.tbDate.Value = "" Or Me.cmbGenre = "" Or Me.tbKeywords = "" Or Me.tbDirector = "" Or Me.tbCast = "" Then
    If MsgBox("Not all forms are completed. Do you want to continue?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo) <> vbYes Then
    Exit Sub
    End If
End If

Set ssheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MovieList")

nr = ssheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
    ssheet.Cells(nr, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
    Else: ssheet.Cells(nr, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
End If

ssheet.Cells(nr, 2) = Me.tbTitle
ssheet.Cells(nr, 3) = Me.tbDate
ssheet.Cells(nr, 4) = Me.cmbGenre
ssheet.Cells(nr, 5) = Me.tbKeywords
ssheet.Cells(nr, 6) = Me.tbDirector
ssheet.Cells(nr, 7) = Me.tbCast
ssheet.Cells(nr, 8) = Me.tbComments

Call resetForm

End Sub

Sub resetForm()

Me.tbTitle = ""
Me.tbDate = ""
Me.cmbGenre = ""
Me.tbKeywords = ""
Me.tbDirector = ""
Me.tbCast = ""
Me.tbComments = ""
Me.tbTitle.SetFocus

End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

'fill combobox
For Each cell In [ListGenre]
    Me.cmbGenre.AddItem
Next cell


End Sub
```

I would be so glad if you could help me. Thank you.

Comment: post an example

Comment: Well you wouldn't see anything. That's the point. The added strings don't move down when I integrate the color stuff.

Comment: where the _"added string"_ are taken from and getting added?

Comment: _"works everytime when I just use strings but every time I try to change the cell interior, it stays on the same row "_ is a bit obscure to me: would you elaborate on it?

Comment: `ssheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` looks from last row in column 1 upwards till it finds any **value** within a cell and if so it gets the row number. But you seems not to store any values into column 1 only interiors. So the command will always find the same row, the last one with a **value** in column 1. Try `ssheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row` this looks in column 2 where you are storing values.

Comment: @AxelRichter, I thought about that too but it wouldn't explain why _"It works everytime when I just use strings"_. That's why I asked SirDrake for some more explanations. Maybe he's not really that glad to be helped...

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly your above code, you have issues with empty cells.

If you do not have any string in your 1 column you need to add some, but if you whan to have "empty" cell, and colored at the same time, you can do it like this.

Ok, between this two parts of your code:

```
If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
     ssheet.Cells(nr, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
  Else: ssheet.Cells(nr, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 3 
End If
```

and this one:

```
ssheet.Cells(nr, 2) = Me.tbTitle 
ssheet.Cells(nr, 3) = Me.tbDate
ssheet.Cells(nr, 4) = Me.cmbGenre 
ssheet.Cells(nr, 5) = Me.tbKeywords 
ssheet.Cells(nr, 6) = Me.tbDirector 
ssheet.Cells(nr, 7) = Me.tbCast 
ssheet.Cells(nr, 8) = Me.tbComments
```

You need to put this line:

```
ssheet.Cells(nr, 1) = " "
```

You'll get what you want!